# Next.js, Pages Still Generated When Components Error

Tags: nextjs

We have a `Next.js` implementation on Vercel connected to `Experience Edge`. We noticed that when components error out, the page that contains the component is still generated. This results in public-facing pages with chunks of missing content. Next.js builds the entire page but where the component is supposed to go is entirely blank.

Instead of considering a page valid, we instead want the page to fail validation and not generate/regenerate. At times the failure is mundane, such as the connection to Edge getting dropped momentarily. Instead of generating a half-baked version of the page, we would much prefer to keep the original copy of the page up.

`Next.js` revalidation is supposed to work this way. When it experiences an error, it should not validate a page, but with the `Sitecore Next.js SDK` it does.

Is it possible to skip validating a page when a component errors?

Sitecore-jss-nextjs: `^20.1.3`

Next: `^12.3.3`

Comment: Do you run `start:production` or `start:connected`? The first on does prevent starting of rendering container with broken pages.

Comment: This is not only an issue locally but on Vercel as well during a proper build. It also occurs during revalidation. getStaticPaths does not think there is a failure because it isn't notified of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct that `getStaticProps` DOES in fact not validate a page that it receives an error on. The issue is that Sitecore swallows the errors that occur within components:

[image: component error]

Therefore, when `getStaticProps` finishes executing the page, it assumes all is well and thus you get a page with missing `content/components`.

Luckily, this is easily solvable because the error is accessible in the `componentProps` property of `props`. Also, since `getStaticProps` implements the `SitecorePagePropsFactory`, we can add an additional plugin without disturbing the existing code.

Add the following code under

- lib

  - page-props-factory

    - plugins

Name: **fail-on-component-error.ts**

```
import { SitecorePageProps } from 'lib/page-props';
import { Plugin } from '..';

class FailOnComponentErrorPlugin implements Plugin {
  order = 2;

  async exec(props: SitecorePageProps) {
    const componentErrors = Object.keys(props?.componentProps ?? {})
      ?.filter((component) => (props?.componentProps?.[component] as { error: string })?.error)
      .map((key) => `${key}: ${(props?.componentProps?.[key] as { error: string })?.error}`);

    if (componentErrors.length > 0) {
      throw new Error(
        `[GET STATIC PATHS]. An error occurred processing ${
          props?.layoutData?.sitecore?.route?.name
        }, message: ${componentErrors.join(' .. ')}`
      );
    }

    return props;
  }
}

export const failOnComponentErrorPlugin = new FailOnComponentErrorPlugin();
```

This code will cycle through the `componentProps` collection to find any components that are outputting an error. It then concatenates the unique rendering ID's and error messages into a single output.

This will not only stop builds from succeeding on errors, but also revalidation (ISR or On-Demand Revalidation).